# Vectorizing code in pandas by avoiding loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Consider the below df:

```
In [448]: complex_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'stat_A': [120, 121, 122, 123],
     ...:                                       'group_id_A': [1, 1, 1, 2],
     ...:                                       'level_A': [1, 2, 2, 1],
     ...:                                       'stat_B': [220, 221, 222, 223],
     ...:                                       'group_id_B': [1, 1, 1, 2],
     ...:                                       'level_B': [1, 1, 2, 2],
     ...:                                       'stat_C': ['aa', 'ab', 'aa', 'ab'],
     ...:                                       'measure_avg_A': [10.5, 11, 20, 12],
     ...:                                       'measure_sum_B': [10, 20, 30, 40]}
     ...:                                      )

In [449]: complex_dataframe
Out[449]: 
   stat_A  group_id_A  level_A  stat_B  group_id_B  level_B stat_C  measure_avg_A  measure_sum_B
0     120           1        1     220           1        1     aa           10.5             10
1     121           1        2     221           1        1     ab           11.0             20
2     122           1        2     222           1        2     aa           20.0             30
3     123           2        1     223           2        2     ab           12.0             40
```

Here the variables which have all 3 columns : `stat_`, `group_id_` & `level_` are `complex` columns and the ones with just `stat_` are simple columns.

So, columns `A` and `B` above are complex columns. Column `C` is a simple column and columns that start with `measure_` are mere values.

The use-case is:

I need to group on all `group_id_` columns and simple columns. In above case groupby on: `group_id_A`,`group_id_B`,`stat_C`.

Expected Output:

[image]

where `measure_A` column is like:

[image]

I've already coded for this using multiple loops.

```
from collections import Counter

cols_without_measures = complex_dataframe.loc[:, ~complex_dataframe.columns.str.startswith("measure_")].columns.tolist()
cols_without_measures = [i.split('_')[-1] for i in cols_without_measures]
counter = Counter(cols_without_measures)

complex_cols = [k for k, v in counter.items() if v == 3]
simple_cols = list(set(list(counter.keys())).symmetric_difference(set(complex_cols)))
grouped_cols = ['group_id_' + i for i in complex_cols] + ['stat_' + i for i in simple_cols]

grp = self.df_in.groupby(grouped_cols)
complex_df = pd.DataFrame()

for k, v in grp:
    temp = v.loc[:, ~v.columns.isin(grouped_cols)]
    stat_df = temp.loc[:, ~temp.columns.str.startswith('measure_')]
    measure_df = temp.filter(like='measure_', axis=1)
    out_df = v[grouped_cols].head(1)
    for i in measure_df.columns:
        m = stat_df.copy()
        m[i] = measure_df[i]
        out_df[i] = [m.to_dict()]
    complex_df = complex_df.append(out_df)
```

Is there any better way to solve this? Perhaps make it vectorized in some way.

Comment: @jezrael Can you please have a look at this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and concatenate them using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) over axis 1

```
def d(x):
    return x.to_dict()
g = df.groupby(['group_id_A','group_id_B','stat_C'])
one = g[['stat_A','level_A','stat_B','level_B','measure_avg_A']].apply(d)
two = g[['stat_A','level_A','stat_B','level_B','measure_sum_B']].apply(d)

out = pd.concat([one, two], axis=1)
out.columns = ['measure_avg_A', 'measure_sum_B']
```

Borrowing some code from anky :P

```
display = print
final = out 

                                                                  measure_avg_A                                      measure_sum_B
group_id_A group_id_B stat_C                                                                                                      
1          1          aa      {'stat_A': {0: 120, 2: 122}, 'level_A': {0: 1,...  {'stat_A': {0: 120, 2: 122}, 'level_A': {0: 1,...
                      ab      {'stat_A': {1: 121}, 'level_A': {1: 2}, 'stat_...  {'stat_A': {1: 121}, 'level_A': {1: 2}, 'stat_...
2          2          ab      {'stat_A': {3: 123}, 'level_A': {3: 1}, 'stat_...  {'stat_A': {3: 123}, 'level_A': {3: 1}, 'stat_...

   stat_A  level_A  stat_B  level_B  measure_avg_A
0     120        1     220        1           10.5
2     122        2     222        2           20.0

   stat_A  level_A  stat_B  level_B  measure_avg_A
1     121        2     221        1           11.0

   stat_A  level_A  stat_B  level_B  measure_sum_B
0     120        1     220        1             10
2     122        2     222        2             30

   stat_A  level_A  stat_B  level_B  measure_sum_B
1     121        2     221        1             20
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with groupby in pandas, but it's using apply with a lambda. This is not a fully vectorized solution.

```
df_complex = complex_dataframe.groupby(['group_id_A','group_id_B','stat_C']).apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series({
        'measure_avg_A': x[['stat_A','level_A','stat_B','level_B','measure_avg_A']].to_dict(),
        'measure_sum_B': x[['stat_A','level_A','stat_B','level_B','measure_sum_B']].to_dict()
    })).reset_index()
```

Then you can query the dataframe like you wanted

```
pd.DataFrame(df_complex.at[0, 'measure_avg_A'])
```

Output

```
   stat_A  level_A  stat_B  level_B  measure_avg_A
0     120        1     220        1           10.5
2     122        2     222        2           20.0
```

Comment: Although this is a possible solution, I would recommend to reconsider your data layout. A simpler dataframe can likely archive the same functionallity.

Comment: This looks good, the only thing being, the columns used in `pd.Series` can be multiple. Would I have to loop them?

Comment: If you have many columns to create, I would use a ```dictionary comprehension``` inside the pd.Series. But be aware, this is most likely not a good solution. Except you have necessary requirements to create many dataframes/dicts inside a dataframe.

Comment: I understand that. Can you please provide the solution using `dict comprehension` in the `apply` statement in your answer.

Comment: Sorry, no time at the moment. Perhaps it's a good topic for another question?

Comment: No issues. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is any better , but you can try and let me know:

```
measure_cols = [*complex_dataframe.columns[complex_dataframe.columns
                                           .str.contains("measure")]]
u = complex_dataframe.set_index(grouped_cols)

final=pd.concat([u[u.columns.difference(measure_cols,sort=False).union([i],sort=False)]
        .groupby(grouped_cols).apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True).to_dict())
        .rename(i)   for i in measure_cols],axis=1).reset_index()
```

---

```
display(final)
display(pd.DataFrame(final['measure_avg_A'].iat[0]))
display(pd.DataFrame(final['measure_avg_A'].iat[1]))
display(pd.DataFrame(final['measure_sum_B'].iat[0]))
display(pd.DataFrame(final['measure_sum_B'].iat[1]))
```

[image]

Comment: Solution runs fine. Looks like avoiding `for` loops completely is not possible. Too many functions used here, kind of complicates things a bit.

Comment: @MayankPorwal thanks for confirming, I cant wrap my head at this point for a no loop solution. :/ sorry..!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to access the grouped DataFrames by a more logical index you could do this:

```
df_grouped = complex_dataframe.groupby(['group_id_A', 'group_id_B', 'stat_C'])
```

Then you would access each of the groups by a tuple of the values you grouped by:

```
df_grouped.get_group((1, 1, 'ab'))
```

gives you the DataFrame

```
        stat_A  group_id_A  level_A stat_B  group_id_B  level_B stat_C measure_avg_A    measure_sum_B
    1   121     1           2       21      1           1       ab     11.0             20
```

You can iterate through the groups with:

```
for key, item in df_grouped:
    print(key, "\n")
    print(df_grouped.get_group(key), "\n\n")
```